# How to prevent $\centering$ from making my graphs bold?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, input

I need to display two graphs side by side, which are in stored as two exteral `.tex` files. This is what I've got:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{C4/images/experimentone/temp_over_time_plot}}
      \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}
    \centering
        \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{C4/images/experimenttwo/temp_over_time_plot}}
    \end{subfigure}
     \label{fig:Experiences 1 et 2}
    \caption{Graphes des températures des gaz $T_g_1$, $T_g_2$ et $T_g_3$ en fonction du temps pour la 1ère et 2ème expérience respectivement.}
\end{figure}
```

Which does the job of aligning the graphs but displays them in a bold font, as seen in the following picture:

[image]

I discovered that the `\centering` tag was adding this extra 'boldness'. The thing is, when I remove these tags, I'm left with:

[image]

Which displays them in the correct thin-latex-like style, but doesn't center them. So, any of the following solutions would help a lot:

1. Find a replacement to `\centering` or remove the extra boldness this tag adds up
2. Find another way altogether to display two `\input` side by side, maybe with a different package than `subfigure`

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: The `subfigure` package is widely considered obsolete. I suggest using the `subcaption` package, which also has its own subfigure environment (though you'll need to add an argument for the width of each subfigure). See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables#Subfigures). The `.5!`s in the corners make me think your current code generates errors, which you should never ignore. (I think the subfigure environment is gobbling the command that comes after it since it expects an argument.)

Comment: What's in the files `C4/images/experimentone/temp_over_time_plot.tex` and `C4/images/experimenttwo/temp_over_time_plot.tex`?

Comment: Off-topic: The `\label` statement should come after, not before, the `\caption` statement.

Comment: The terms `$T_g_1$, $T_g_2$ et $T_g_3$` must be spewing "double-subscript" warning messages. I think you shoud write either `$T_{g_1}$, $T_{g_2}$ et $T_{g_3}$` or `$T_{g1}$, $T_{g2}$ et $T_{g3}$`.

Comment: `\centering` has no effect on fonts

Comment: I have to say I don't see much difference between the two screenshots. Maybe the 'boldness' is just caused by the size of the graphs? The upper screenshot looks a bit smaller, presumably there the two graphs fit in the page width, while in the second screenshot the graph clearly falls outside of the page margin and must therefore be bigger than the centered version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted, `\centering` has no effect on fonts, let alone font weights.

I think you're looking for something like the following example, which employs the `subcaption` package. Observe that each `subfigure` takes a mandatory argument: the desidered width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}     % for 'subfigure' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C4/images/experimentone/temp_over_time_plot}
    \caption{\dots}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C4/images/experimenttwo/temp_over_time_plot}
    \caption{\dots}
    \end{subfigure}
     
    \caption{Graphes des températures des gaz $T_{g1}$, $T_{g2}$ et $T_{g3}$ en fonction du temps pour la 1ère et 2ème expérience respectivement.}
    \label{fig:Experiences 1 et 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use ``\includegraphics``. How would you do this with ``\input`` 
 @Mico ?

Comment: @sleepydrmike - I asked earlier: What's in the files `C4/images/experimentone/temp_over_time_plot.tex` and `C4/images/experimenttwo/temp_over_time_plot.tex`?

Comment: My bad, didn't see it. Well they have the whole graph. I built it with gnuplot and cairolatex

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was to change your ``\includegraphics...`` line by ``\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{C4/images/experimentone/temp_over_time_plot}}``